# Why finalize() method has empty body?

Tags: object, garbage-collection, finalize

This is how the finalize() is defined in Object class:
protected void finalize() throws Throwable { }

Can anyone tell me where is the code inside the method?  I mean how Garbage Collector calls a method with empty body to perform cleanup activities associated with the object?

Comment: There is no code in there. The GC calls the method, and it *does nothing*. That is: by default. You can overwrite the method in your custom `Object` subclasses to do something.

Comment: What cleanup activities do you expect it to do? In other words, what code did you expect to find in that method body?